# how to save images in fragment in webview on long presson the image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

hi guys i want that user can save images(which are displayed inside fragment webview) to there  gallery.I want that user will able to save image to there gallery which is displayed in webview. i checked the internet but non of the code work for me. can you give me a complete working code according to my fragment code . im new to android studio and a 10th grade student pls help me

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public Handler h;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public AdView adView;
    public WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
           mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public BlankFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view
                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);




    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.hu);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://stockphoto.com/search.php?q=poo+emoji");


        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }



            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Anshul. You have post your error, what methods you have tried already so that we can help you. For complete working codes follow other tutorials

Comment: https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/10/android-save-image-from-webview.html     . i tried this code, the code is written for activity not for fragment  but i edited code for fragment but didnt work for me

Comment: can you pls send a complete code on my mail anshul348567890@gmail.com .

Comment: i want to show user a prompt to save image when he long press the images which is displayed in webpage inside fragment

Comment: I think you're mistaken about this website. We only help not send codes. Refrain from doing this again on this website or you will be blocked

Comment: so pls help me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode HTML:

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            yahoo.openStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);

in.close();
```

After that get Image Tag from it then you can get mages from it and write to sd card.

Comment: can you pls send a complete code on my mail anshul348567890@gmail.com . im new to android and dont know how to decode html , i even dont know how to get image from fragment webpage to save it in gallery . can i make a toast  when image get saved in gallery  and when image fail to save in gallery . plss give me a complete code on my mail or here plss bro.   :)

Comment: i want to show user a prompt to save image when he long press the images which is displayed in webpage inside fragment